# Remap / reinstall network settings after hardware change - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking

yesterday I tested the limits by putting a harddrive with installed Ubuntu into a different (IBM X41 to other IBM X41; not too much different) computer. The effect looks good, everything starts fine, only network "initialisation" waits (it says "Waiting for network configuration..." while starting), waits another 5 seconds and then starts without a network connection. Obviously there is different networking hardware installed. So what can I do now? Reinstalling Ubuntu with a stick would be easy, but not my favored way.

Therefore my question is:

How can I "remap" the installed hardware for networking drivers and networking settings a it is done when booting from a stick or installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Found a solution that worked for me:
      -      
'lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net'
      -      
to see the devices and the drivers
      -      
'sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces'
to delete all settings for interfaces that do not exist

Comment: Might want to add that as an answer to your question and mark it as the answer, so people with the same issue can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping of hardware to Ubuntu network device is in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.

The trouble is that when you moved the disk to new hardware, new mappings were made for the network devices that don't match what is in `/etc/network/interfaces`. If you do `ifconfig -a`, you will probably see what is going on.

Remove `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and reboot. On boot it will be reconstructed, and you should have a set of devices that match the definitions in `/etc/network/interfaces`.